# ReadFile and keep order consistent

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading logfiles and every line provides a timestamp. In the logfiles the order is always correct but there can be multiple instances of the same timestamp. If we look at the little example down below I want to make sure that whenever I work with the dataset Start will be looked at before RecStart. (this does not reflect my actual data / status possibilities)

```
system1;2017-07-04T08:33:26;Start;Start execution
system1;2017-07-04T08:33:26;RecStart;Start recorder
```

I read from files with `spark.read.textFile(file.path)`

I read about monotonically_increasing_id but it does not guarantee that the IDs are sequential.
I read that groupBy is not bound to keep the order. Is it the same for partitionBy? If partitionBy always keeps the order correct then the following command should solve my problems
 `val ds2 = ds 
  .withColumn("rn",row_number.over(Window.partitionBy($"systemname").orderBy($"timestamp")`

I also thought about adding the milliseconds of current time to the timestamp while reading the file but this also doesn't seem save because of parallelism.

Is there a way to make sure the order will be the same as in the text files?

Comment: the column with `Start` and `RecStart` can only have these two values?

Comment: No there is very large variety of values. This is just a little example. I think what I wrote is confusing. The "always Start before recStart" thing is only refering to this little example not in general to my dataset

Comment: You can read the file as RDD then use zipWithIndex to get the index of each row.